# Mapping of .properties file via Spring configuration XML

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I made a `message.validation.properties` file inside `root/src/resources` and my code below inside the `spring-servlet.xml` is not recognized.

```
<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames">
      <list>
          <value>src/resources/messages.validation</value>
      </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I have tried `classpath:messages.validation`, `messages.validation` but I only get the warning message

```
WARNING: ResourceBundle [src/resources/messages.validation] not found for MessageSource: Can't find bundle for base name src/resources/messages.validation, locale en_US
```

How can I locate this file? Note that I do not want to put it in another folder ie. `WEB-INF/classes`.

Comment: No, I'm not using maven.

Comment: Is your src/resources folder in classpath ?

Comment: @Raju, yes I have set it (for your confirmation, I did: `Build Path > Source Folder > Add > Select src/resources`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on how you build your project, but in the end the `message.validation.properties` file should up on the classpath, ie. `WEB-INF/classes`. If it is directly in there, you would specify

```
<value>classpath:messages.validation</value>
```

I'll assume that your `src` folder is a source folder in your IDE. As such, anything under it will be compiled/copied so that it ends up in the classpath directory. As such, you should be using

```
<value>classpath:resources/messages.validation</value>
```

Again, if `/src/resources` is the source folder, then you need

```
<value>classpath:messages.validation</value>
```

Comment: (1) I restarted my Eclipse (2) re-attached `src/resources` to the classpath and it is working now as intended - reading the contents of `messages.properties`.

Comment: Hello Mr. Delimanolis, I am now working on a Tomcat server and my files are not found. I have the path `/home/my_username/tomcat7/resources` declared in my `.properties` file but it shows a `NullPointerException`. Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: @PASTRY You'll have to give more details. Where is the `NullPointerException` occurring?  Consider asking a new question, providing all the relevant details after analysing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the resource folder to the classpath so it can become accessible.

If you use Eclipse, right-click on project, select Properties. Then on the left side select "Java build path" and add you resource directory with "Add Class Folder".

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<value>classpath:messages.validation</value>
```