# Tomcat deployment file paths (for Java I/O process)

Tags: java, spring, file-io, deployment, tomcat7

I managed to implement a simple file I/O in my Spring project for files not inside my project (then `WAR` file) using a `.properties` file that contains the path ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21820779/3287503)) and now I need to do it in the server.

Before, when I included the files inside the `WAR` file, I can access them in the Tomcat server using the path

```
/home/my_username/tomcat7/webapps/my_project/WEB-INF/classes/
```

But now that the files are not inside the `WAR` file, I just put them adjacent to the `webapps` folder.

The structure of my Tomcat 7 folder is:

```
tomcat7
|----> bin
|----> conf
|----> logs
|----> resources*
|----> temp
|----> webapps
|----\----> springapp.war*
|----> work
```

where `/resources` is the folder I need inside the `WAR` file I/O.

My `.properties` file has:

```
dir.server=home/my_username/tomcat7/resources
// or
dir.server=/home/my_username/tomcat7/resources
```

but an error shows (from my `catalina.out` file):

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/my_username/tomcat7/resources/my_file.file (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:120)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:79)
    at weka.core.SerializationHelper.read(SerializationHelper.java:270)
```

Is there a proper way to declare the file path or do I have to change my implementation of file I/O?

Comment: Definitely starting with a slash. Also needs setting the correct recursive `chown owner:group` and `chmod a+rw` rights. On the FileNotFoundException you might want to try to unwind the path upto the root to find the correct offending directory `/home/my_username` or so.

Comment: If I understand correctly, I need to make the permissions of `/resources` to `755` (and recursively)?

Comment: Yes, if that is the problem; read rights should suffice if you do only reading `chmod a+r`.

Comment: It is still giving a null pointer exception but thank you for this information!

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are getting a `FileNotFoundException` is because your deployed `war` must be on another system or something like that that that doesn't contain the same exact path. You should use this line of code in your program.

```
String tomcatPath = System.getProperty("catalina.base")
```

This will return you the path to the tomcat folder in that particular system. Hence if system on which you deployed the `war` has a different path for tomcat, that will be returned. You can then access the properties file in the resources folder by appending the string to the path.

```
String tomcatPath = System.getProperty("catalina.base");
String propertiesFilePath = tomcatPath + "/resources";
```

To access a particular file you can use the code:

```
String filePath = propertiesFilePath+"my_file.file";
```

You should take a look at :

[How to get Tomcat installation directory using Java.](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-get-the-tomcat-home-directory-in-java/)

Hope it helps.. :)

Comment: It's still not working though :( the output of `System.getProperty("catalina.base")` is actually the same as the one I currently use in the question.

Comment: Should I move the folder `resources` elsewhere?

Comment: Did you try running the `getProperty` on the server.? What is the output on that machine.. ?

Comment: Try debugging it. Access the file normally using a simple java program and see it you hit the same roadblock. If so there can be a problem with privileges of the system as @Joop mentioned.